# weights and biases from hdf5 file

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, hdf5

I'm using Keras and Tensorflow to train a neural network. Via the early stopping callback I am saving hdf5 files containing weights and biases:

```
file_path = "data/weights-improvement-{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.2f}.hdf5"

save_best_callback = ModelCheckpoint(file_path, monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True,
                                     save_weights_only=False, mode='auto', period=1)


# model
visible = Input(shape=(36,))

x = Dense(40, activation='tanh')(visible) 
x = Dense(45, activation='tanh')(x) 
x = Dense(30, activation='tanh')(x) 
x = Dense(55, activation='tanh')(x)

output = Dense(5, activation='tanh')(x)
```

Normally, I use

```
weights_1 = model.layers[1].get_weights()[0]
biases_1 = model.layers[1].get_weights()[1]
```

for one layer.

Somehow, the weights and biases could not be saved when I ran my script overnight (which is unusual, a hdf5 file failed to create). Now I have multiple hdf5 files left from which I want to choose the last one that could be saved to load my weights and biases.

I want the weight matrix of each layer to have the form (#cells x #inputs) and the bias matrix to have the form (#cells x 1), while for layer j=1 #inputs = 36 and for j>1 inputs = #cells(j-1). Then those matrices should be stored as numpy arrays.

In total I have 5 layers, which should give me 5 weight and bias matrices. I tried loading a hdf5-file with pandas:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

array = np.fromfile('data/weights-improvement-446-0.00.hdf5', dtype=float)
df_array = pd.DataFrame(array)
print(df_array)
```

but this just gives me a dataframe consisting of 1 column and m rows, where some elements are 'NaN'. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't load an HDF5 with numpy, you need to use the hdf5 library (like h5py).

Comment: It is possible to load it, it just doesn't match with my purposes.

Comment: Yes, it does not match because you are using the wrong API, np.fromfile does not support the HDF5 format and it is just interpreting the whole file as binary data, which explains why you get incorrect values

Comment: I agree with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use keras load_model API? If it's only the weights, use the load_weights API.

```
>>> from keras.models import load_model
>>> model = load_model('data/weights-improvement-446-0.00.hdf5')
>>> for layer in model.layers:
>>>     if len(layer.weights) > 0:
>>>         print(layer.name, layer.weights[0].shape)
```

Comment: I did not know that I could load the model like this. Instead of using 'layer.weights[0].shape' I used 'model.layers[1].get_weights()[0]' which worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Function to read saved Keras (tensorflow) weights from hdf5 file:

```
import os
import h5py
import numpy as np

def print_model_h5_wegiths(weight_file_path):
    # weights tensor is stored in the value of the Dataset, and each episode will have attrs to store the attributes of each network layer

    f = h5py.File(weight_file_path) # read weights h5 file and return File class
    try:
        if len(f.attrs.items()):
            print("{} contains: ".format(f.filename)) # weight_file_path
            print("Root attributes:")
        for key, value in f.attrs.items():
            print(" {}: {}".format(key, value))
            # Output the attrs information stored in the File class, generally the name of each layer: layer_names/backend/keras_version

        for layer, g in f.items():
            # Read the name of each layer and the Group class containing layer information
            print(" {} with Group: {}".format(layer, g)) # model_weights with Group: <HDF5 (22 members)>),
            print(" Attributes:")
            for key, value in g.attrs.items():
                # Output the attrs information stored in the Group class, generally the weights and biases of each layer and their names
                # eg ;weight_names: [b'attention_2/q_kernel:0' b'attention_2/k_kernel:0' b'attention_2/w_kernel:0']
                print(" {}: {}".format(key, value))
                #
                print(" Dataset:") # np.array(f.get(key)).shape()
            for name, d in g.items(): # Read the Dataset class that stores specific information in each layer
                print('name:', name, d)

                if str(f.filename).endswith('.weights'):
                    for k, v in d.items():
                        # Output the layer name and weight stored in the Dataset, or print the attrs of the dataset
                        # k, v embeddings:0 <HDF5 dataset "embeddings:0": shape (21, 128), type "<f4">
                        print(' {} with shape: {} or {}'.format(k, np.array(d.get(k)).shape, np.array(v).shape))
                        print(" {} have weights: {}".format(k, np.array(v))) # Weights of each layer
                        print(str(k))
                if str(f.filename).endswith('.h5'):
                    for k, v in d.items(): # v is equivalent to d.get(k)
                        print(k, v)
                        print(' {} with shape: {} or {}'.format(k, np.array(d.get(k)).shape, np.array(v).shape))
                        print(" {} have weights: {}".format(k, np.array(v))) # Weights of each layer
                        print(str(k))

                        # Adam <HDF5 group "/optimizer_weights/training/Adam" (63 members)>

    finally:
        f.close()

print('Current working path:', os.getcwd())
h5_weight = r'modelx.h5'
print_model_h5_wegiths(h5_weight)
```